# converting elements in an array that represent keycodes into char

Tags: javascript

if I have an array where each element represents the keycode of a keypress (e.g. [49,49,49,49]), is there a way I can convert each element in the array to the char that the keycode is associated with (i.e., [49,49,49,49] ->  [1,1,1,1])

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if it is possible to replace what you are doing with higher level code, I suggest using a library for handling keyboard events. (for example https://craig.is/killing/mice)

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.fromCharCode`.

```js
var input = 49;
var result = String.fromCharCode(input); //Converts char code to string
var resultInInteger = parseInt(result); //Converts string to number
alert(typeof result + ' - ' + result);
alert(typeof resultInInteger + ' - ' + resultInInteger);
```

More Info about `String.fromCharCode` can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp)